# JavaScript for/in loop with unexpected output

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure why this outputs `undefined` for the property names of the `document` object. I think it has something to do with the variable expression `myArray[i++]`. I could make this a simple primitive variable and I'll get all the property names, but I would like all the property names saved into an array. Thank you for your help in advance!!

```
var myArray = [];
var i = 0;
for (myArray[i++] in document) {
document.write(myArray[i] + "</br>");
}
```

Comment: Wow, I would have expected for this to throw a syntax error. I really don't encourage to use code like this, but the problem is that at the moment you are accessing `myArray[i]`, the index does not exist yet (`i` was incremented in `myArray[i++]`). `document.write(myArray[i-1] + "</br>");` works though.

Comment: This is the syntax for a `for/in` loop, not a `for` loop. This should enumerate the properties of the object. If it is invalid, where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Dusty, it's just unusual; you usually see an unqualified identifier on the left side of `in` (just a variable, no brackets or dots).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is happening because you are always look one element further in the array than you've defined, since you post-increment `i`. You could pre-increment instead:

```
var myArray = [];
var i = -1;
for (myArray[++i] in document) {
    document.write(myArray[i] + "</br>");
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pXmCD/)

Comment: Nice haha, I was adding the hyphens in post and pre-increment during those 4 seconds lol. I upvoted your answer.

Comment: This won't give all property names.

Comment: You're welcome @Dusty! I posted a JSFiddle for your convenience, however, it would be awesome to get into the habit of using `console.log`. It will make writing Javascript a lot easier.

Comment: I have a follow up question... wouldn't initializing `i` to `0` and post incrementing be the same?

Comment: @Dusty The way you had it originally, on the first iteration you are assigning the first property to `myArray[0]` and then calling `document.write(myArray[1])` since `i` has been incremeneted. If you post-increment in the document.write like Dagg Nabbit did in his answer, you'll also get the correct result.

Comment: I thought through the first iteration it would be `document.write(myArray[0])`. Is `myArray[i++]` incrementing `i` before the first loop iteration? I thought that since `++` was on the right side of the variable, that it was getting incremented after the first iteration.

Comment: @Dusty Post increment means that it increments after it's value is returned. `i++` increments `i` and then evaluates to the original value of `i`.

Comment: @Dusty So if you say `var x = 2; var y = x++;` You are assigning the value 2 to `y` and `x` is now `3`. Whereas if you do `var x =2; var y = ++x;` both `x` and `y` get the value `3`.

Comment: After the expression `x` is always incremented, so in any expressions which come afterwards, it doesn't make a difference whether you used preincrement or postincrement, `i` has been incremented already either way.

Comment: Thanks sooo much Paulpro! That last comment is what confirmed what I was thinking. That whole expression between the `(...)` evaluates, `i` gets incremented, and then the loop executes. I think i got it.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because you increment `i` after setting `myArray[i]` by doing `myArray[i++]` (post increment).

This would work, although I'm not sure why you'd need to do it.

```
var myArray = [];
var i = 0;
for (myArray[i] in document) {
    console.log(myArray[i++] + "</br>");
}
```

Comment: This won't give all property names.

Comment: @yowza I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Because non-enumerable properties are a part of all properties.

Comment: Thanks for the great post! Am I able to see that this code works in jsfiddle... sorry, not to familiar with `console.log`.

Comment: @Dusty most browsers have a console that you can open, usually with the F12 key. `console.log` just dumps stuff to the console.

Comment: I'm familiar with consoles... just curious if I can view the console log in jsfiddle?

Comment: F12 in Chrome or IE (I think), or Ctrl-shift-K in FF will open the console for jsfiddle the same as for any other site.

Answer (score 1):

> *"I would like all the property names saved into an array. "*

You could do:

```
var names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(document);
```

The reason for `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` is that it includes non-enumerable properties, whereas `for-in` will skip them.

But some properties are inherited, so you'd need to do the same on all objects in the prototype chain if that's what you want.

```
var obj = document;
var names = [];

do {
    names.push.apply(names, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
} while(obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
```

---

Result in Firefox:

> ["jQuery17104169501299363202", "location", "addEventListener", "removeEventListener", "dispatchEvent", "getElementsByName", "getItems", "open", "close", "write", "writeln", "execCommand", "queryCommandEnabled", "queryCommandIndeterm", "queryCommandState", "queryCommandSupported", "queryCommandValue", "clear", "getSelection", "captureEvents", "releaseEvents", "routeEvent", "domain", "cookie", "body", "head", "images", "embeds", "plugins", "links", "forms", "scripts", "designMode", "fgColor", "linkColor", "vlinkColor", "alinkColor", "bgColor", "anchors", "applets", "onreadystatechange", "onmouseenter", "onmouseleave", "getElementsByTagName", "getElementsByTagNameNS", "getElementsByClassName", "getElementById", "createElement", "createElementNS", "createDocumentFragment", "createTextNode", "createComment", "createProcessingInstruction", "importNode", "adoptNode", "createEvent", "createRange", "createNodeIterator", "createTreeWalker", "createCDATASection", "createAttribute", "createAttributeNS", "hasFocus", "releaseCapture", "mozSetImageElement", "mozCancelFullScreen", "mozExitPointerLock", "enableStyleSheetsForSet", "elementFromPoint", "querySelector", "querySelectorAll", "getAnonymousNodes", "getAnonymousElementByAttribute", "addBinding", "removeBinding", "getBindingParent", "loadBindingDocument", "createExpression", "createNSResolver", "evaluate", "implementation", "URL", "documentURI", "compatMode", "characterSet", "contentType", "doctype", "documentElement", "inputEncoding", "referrer", "lastModified", "readyState", "title", "dir", "defaultView", "activeElement", "currentScript", "mozFullScreenEnabled", "mozFullScreenElement", "mozFullScreen", "mozPointerLockElement", "hidden", "mozHidden", "visibilityState", "mozVisibilityState", "styleSheets", "selectedStyleSheetSet", "lastStyleSheetSet", "preferredStyleSheetSet", "styleSheetSets", "hasChildNodes", "insertBefore", "appendChild", "replaceChild", "removeChild", "normalize", "cloneNode", "isEqualNode", "compareDocumentPosition", "contains", "lookupPrefix", "lookupNamespaceURI", "isDefaultNamespace", "isSupported", "hasAttributes", "setUserData", "getUserData", "nodeType", "nodeName", "baseURI", "ownerDocument", "parentNode", "parentElement", "childNodes", "firstChild", "lastChild", "previousSibling", "nextSibling", "nodeValue", "textContent", "attributes", "namespaceURI", "prefix", "localName", "**lookupGetter**", "**lookupSetter**", "**defineGetter**", "**defineSetter**", "QueryInterface", "mozSyntheticDocument", "caretPositionFromPoint", "ELEMENT_NODE", "ATTRIBUTE_NODE", "TEXT_NODE", "CDATA_SECTION_NODE", "ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE", "ENTITY_NODE", "PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE", "COMMENT_NODE", "DOCUMENT_NODE", "DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE", "DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE", "NOTATION_NODE", "DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED", "DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING", "DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING", "DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS", "DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY", "DOCUMENT_POSITION_IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC", "location", "onabort", "onblur", "oncanplay", "oncanplaythrough", "onchange", "onclick", "oncontextmenu", "ondblclick", "ondrag", "ondragend", "ondragenter", "ondragleave", "ondragover", "ondragstart", "ondrop", "ondurationchange", "onemptied", "onended", "onerror", "onfocus", "oninput", "oninvalid", "onkeydown", "onkeypress", "onkeyup", "onload", "onloadeddata", "onloadedmetadata", "onloadstart", "onmousedown", "onmousemove", "onmouseout", "onmouseover", "onmouseup", "onmozfullscreenchange", "onmozfullscreenerror", "onmozpointerlockchange", "onmozpointerlockerror", "onpause", "onplay", "onplaying", "onprogress", "onratechange", "onreset", "onscroll", "onseeked", "onseeking", "onselect", "onshow", "onstalled", "onsubmit", "onsuspend", "ontimeupdate", "onvolumechange", "onwaiting", "onwheel", "oncopy", "oncut", "onpaste", "onbeforescriptexecute", "onafterscriptexecute", "getElementsByTagName", "getElementsByTagNameNS", "getElementsByClassName", "getElementById", "createElement", "createElementNS", "createDocumentFragment", "createTextNode", "createComment", "createProcessingInstruction", "importNode", "adoptNode", "createEvent", "createRange", "createNodeIterator", "createTreeWalker", "createCDATASection", "createAttribute", "createAttributeNS", "hasFocus", "releaseCapture", "mozSetImageElement", "mozCancelFullScreen", "mozExitPointerLock", "enableStyleSheetsForSet", "elementFromPoint", "querySelector", "querySelectorAll", "getAnonymousNodes", "getAnonymousElementByAttribute", "addBinding", "removeBinding", "getBindingParent", "loadBindingDocument", "createExpression", "createNSResolver", "evaluate", "implementation", "URL", "documentURI", "compatMode", "characterSet", "contentType", "doctype", "documentElement", "inputEncoding", "referrer", "lastModified", "readyState", "title", "dir", "defaultView", "activeElement", "onabort", "onblur", "oncanplay", "oncanplaythrough", "onchange", "onclick", "oncontextmenu", "ondblclick", "ondrag", "ondragend", "ondragenter", "ondragleave", "ondragover", "ondragstart", "ondrop", "ondurationchange", "onemptied", "onended", "onerror", "onfocus", "oninput", "oninvalid", "onkeydown", "onkeypress", "onkeyup", "onload", "onloadeddata", "onloadedmetadata", "onloadstart", "onmousedown", "onmousemove", "onmouseout", "onmouseover", "onmouseup", "onpause", "onplay", "onplaying", "onprogress", "onratechange", "onreset", "onscroll", "onseeked", "onseeking", "onselect", "onshow", "onstalled", "onsubmit", "onsuspend", "ontimeupdate", "onvolumechange", "onwaiting", "onreadystatechange", "onmouseenter", "onmouseleave", "onmozfullscreenchange", "onmozfullscreenerror", "onmozpointerlockchange", "onmozpointerlockerror", "onwheel", "oncopy", "oncut", "onpaste", "onbeforescriptexecute", "onafterscriptexecute", "currentScript", "mozFullScreenEnabled", "mozFullScreenElement", "mozFullScreen", "mozPointerLockElement", "hidden", "mozHidden", "visibilityState", "mozVisibilityState", "styleSheets", "selectedStyleSheetSet", "lastStyleSheetSet", "preferredStyleSheetSet", "styleSheetSets", "constructor", "hasChildNodes", "insertBefore", "appendChild", "replaceChild", "removeChild", "normalize", "cloneNode", "isEqualNode", "compareDocumentPosition", "contains", "lookupPrefix", "lookupNamespaceURI", "isDefaultNamespace", "isSupported", "hasAttributes", "setUserData", "getUserData", "nodeType", "nodeName", "baseURI", "ownerDocument", "parentNode", "parentElement", "childNodes", "firstChild", "lastChild", "previousSibling", "nextSibling", "nodeValue", "textContent", "attributes", "namespaceURI", "prefix", "localName", "ELEMENT_NODE", "ATTRIBUTE_NODE", "TEXT_NODE", "CDATA_SECTION_NODE", "ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE", "ENTITY_NODE", "PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE", "COMMENT_NODE", "DOCUMENT_NODE", "DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE", "DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE", "NOTATION_NODE", "DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED", "DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING", "DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING", "DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS", "DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY", "DOCUMENT_POSITION_IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC", "constructor", "addEventListener", "removeEventListener", "dispatchEvent", "constructor", "constructor", "toSource", "toString", "toLocaleString", "valueOf", "watch", "unwatch", "hasOwnProperty", "isPrototypeOf", "propertyIsEnumerable", "**defineGetter**", "**defineSetter**", "**lookupGetter**", "**lookupSetter**"]

Comment: Wow... That is a bit unnecessary to show don't you think? Maybe you could post the first few properties of document, followed by a `...`.

Comment: Can you explain this syntax? I trying to output the properties using this code in jsfiddle and I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @Dusty: Which syntax? If you mean the `.push.apply...`, basically the `.apply()` lets you pass an array-like collection as individual arguments. Since the `.push()` is variadic, we get an Array of property names using `.getOwnPropertyNames()` then push the entire collection into the Array. The first argument to `.apply()` is needed to set the `this` value of `.push()`.

Comment: @Paulpro: No, it demonstrates exactly what's happening. I don't know if OP wants the full set or not, but it helps show that `for-in` doesn't do what OP wants.

Comment: @yowza How do you know that the OP wants to enumerate non-enumerable properties? Seems counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: @Paulpro: I read the question, and even quoted it in my answer. I'll quote it again *" I would like all the property names saved into an array"*

Comment: I can't really speak for the OP, but it seems to me they're asking more about why their `for..in` loop didn't work as written. (OP states that they can get "all the property names" using other syntax, so even if that isn't "all inheritied and non-enumerable properties" it would seem to be what they want.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: Indications are that OP doesn't know what he wants.

Comment: Well, right now it looks like my original problem was that I was post-incrementing, when I should have been pre-incrementing. But I'm confused because the index number should be at `0` the first time through the loop... no? And does that variable expression get evaluated before the first loop iteration?

Comment: @Dusty: Your loop head was correct, but your loop body was trying to use the same `i` variable, which had been incremented past the point where the assignment happened. To use it in the body, you'd need to subtract it back out. `document.write(myArray[i - 1] + "</br>");`

Comment: OK i see now... I thought that the index number wasn't getting incremented the first time through.

Comment: "Indications are that OP doesn't know what he wants" ... cute. Suppose I asked you to bring me all the things from my glove box. You go out to the car, open the glove box, and grab a bunch of papers from it. You notice that there are some other things in there that are *part of the glove box*... a little light bulb, a latch, some wires. You rip all that stuff out and bring it to me as well, because hey, it was in the glove box too. Only someone who *totally fails at normal human communication* would have thought I wanted  you to fetch those things that were actually *part* of my glove box.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may want to use a loop like the one below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
  document.write(myArray[i] + "</br>");
}
```

Comment: OP isn't trying to get values _from_ `myArray`. The goal is to get the names of all the properties of `document` and _store_ them in the initially empty `myArray`.

Comment: Yup, i gathered that after reading some of the other responses.